# Pegar todos elementos pai

Tags: jquery

Estou com uma situação, onde tenho uma tabela que não possui `class`. Ficando da seguinte maneira:

```
<table>
   <tr> //Pegar aqui
       <td>
           //Aqui continua a tabela
       </td>
   </tr>
   <tr> //Pegar aqui
       <td>
           //Aqui continua a tabela
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Retorno que desejo fazer:

```
<tr>
    //oque tem dentro
</tr>

<tr>
    //oque tem dentro
</tr>
```

Dessa forma, temos tabelas dentro de tabelas. Eu gostaria de pegar toda a lista da primeira `<tr>`. Mas quando seleciono `$("table tr")`, ele entra nos outros elementos e seleciona tudo.

Como faço para selecionar apenas a primeira carreira de `<tr>`, e não entrar dentro delas?

Answer (score 3):

Para resolver o problema realizei o seguinte procedimento:

```
$(b).find("tbody tr:first").siblings().andSelf().each(function(a,b){
    console.log(b)
});
```

Comment: @MauroAlexandre respostas são no campo de respostas, e não devem ser adicionadas na pergunta.

Comment: Certo. Vi no SOen por um MOD sobre isso. Tudo bem.

Comment: Aqui não é o SOen, mas nesse ponto é igual. Pergunta é pergunta, resposta é resposta. Aqui tem umas leituras legais sobre o site: [Help] - Tem também o site Meta, para discutir o funcionamento do SOpt, e esse post é legal como referência: [FAQ da Comunidade](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/699) - Tem esse também, mais específico: [Respondi minha própria pergunta, fiz algo errado?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37)